# How to keep database size low in MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-size

Newbie here.

**TL;DR** : What is the best way to compact data in MongoDB? Will it use much more space than other database systems?

I wanted to create a database for something more or less like a forum. I started learning MySQL, but I don't need a RDBMS for what I want (most of my relations are 1 to 1 (at most, 1 to Many), even if I have a little data redundancy I'd rather store the information as field-and-value pairs of a document, I think it's faster for JSON than the many table joins in MySQL I would otherwise need). I also prefer JavaScript to SQL.

But looking now at the storage requirements, I find nothing like a TINYINT, CHAR(3), etc. I wanted to keep costs down with server's space, but at the same time record a lot of information (time, ratings, votes, comments, tags, karma, favorites, etc.). I hope I'm wrong, but MySQL seems to waste reasonably less space (although I imagine this is compensated in perfomance by MongoDB).

What are the best practices for reducing size in MongoDB? And am I completely wrong in thinking MongoDB uses more space than MySQL and other DBs (disregarding the benefits of joining tables in MySQL to avoid data redundancy)?

So far, these have been the best articles I found on it:
[How to limit MongoDB database size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64065/how-to-limit-mongodb-database-size) *(force size limits on the database)*
https://www.compose.com/articles/sizing-and-trimming-your-mongodb/ *(cap database and release prefetched space)*
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/ *(use* `compact`*, specially on WiredTiger DBs)*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966687/reducing-mongodb-database-file-size *(repairing data, and same as above)*
As @Fyodor Glebov reminds in his answer, there are also 2 compression algorithms: snappy and zlib.

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because data is not normalised the storage requirements generally bigger.

Don't forget about **compression**. When you use gzip it will use more CPU power, but disk size is much smaller than snappy. It depends on your data.

Some MongoDB consultant made benchmarks about different compression algorithms, but this file not public. Maybe some MongoDB guy provide an improved answer ;)

- No compression
- `Snappy` (enabled by default) – very good compression, efficient use of
  resources
- `zlib` (similar to `gzip`) – excellent compression, but more resource
  intensive

see the startup parameter [storage.wiredTiger.collectionConfig.blockCompressor](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.collectionConfig.blockCompressor)

> Default: snappy
>
> New in version 3.0.0.
>
> The default type of compression to use to compress collection data.
>   You can override this on a per-collection basis when creating
>   collections.
>
> Available compressors are:
>
> none snappy zlib storage.wiredTiger.collectionConfig.blockCompressor
>   affects all collections created. If you change the value of
>   storage.wiredTiger.collectionConfig.blockCompressor on an existing
>   MongoDB deployment, all new collections will use the specified
>   compressor. Existing collections will continue to use the compressor
>   specified when they were created, or the default compressor at that
>   time.

Comment: I'm not sure which compression benchmark you're referring to, but some comparisons are included on [New Compression Options in MongoDB 3.0](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30) (official MongoDB blog) and [Wired Tiger - how to reduce your MongoDB hosting costs 10x](http://ilearnasigoalong.blogspot.com.au/2015/03/wired-tiger-how-to-reduce-your-mongdb.html) (a MongoDB Consulting Engineer's blog).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! And to @Stennie 's references! You're right, I'm slowly getting used to the idea that MongoDB's priority isn't disk space (inevitable in denormalization) and that disk space today is rather cheap. I got scared about mentions of it being a resource hog, but it does seem tameable.

Comment: @flen Aside from the `compact` command which links to the current MongoDB manual, the articles you referenced in your description describe the older MMAP storage engine. In MongoDB 3.2+ the default storage engine is WiredTiger, which has significantly different behaviour include data and index compression. Irrespective of storage engine, the underlying data stored in MongoDB has always had types (see [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)) so you can choose more appropriate representations. For example, see: [How should I store boolean values?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27351682/1388319).

Comment: Thank you @Stennie , I noticed the change to WiredTiger but it's a good thing to emphasize it. I know that BSON has different data types, but that's where it hurts... while I can use TINYINT, (VAR)CHAR and ENUM in MySQL as ways to keep data small, in MongoDB ObjectID (for example) takes 12 bytes! Integers in a 64-bit server are always 8 bytes and small strings are also bigger because BSON records length etc. in it. I read somewhere that one can use "false", "true", "max and min keys" as 1 byte values for 4 options (e.g., white, black, light-gray, dark-grey). But this is a bad fix...

Comment: My point was that there are different data types in BSON. For example, numbers can be 32-bit int, 64-bit int, 64-bit float, or decimal (which range from 4 to 16 bytes). Data storage is different as compared to fixed fields in relational tables (eg. compression & schema-on-read) but the schema generally supports use case efficiency rather than storage efficiency. However, the false/true/min/max example you found sounds like misuse: 4 named boolean fields would be saner, or you could use bitwise updates/queries for feature flags in a single `int32` field if storage overhead is a key concern.

Comment: [ObjectIDs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) are pseudorandom identifiers designed to be generated in a distributed system: clients can independently generate ObjectIDs as unique primary keys with a negligible chance of collision. At 12 bytes ObjectIDs are smaller than [UUIDs or GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (which are typically 16 bytes) but you are free to use an alternative `_id`  value instead of the default.